# Real time DataFrame plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame which is updated in a while loop and I would like to plot this in real time, but unfortunately I did not get how to do that.
A samplae code might be:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import time as tm
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import pandas as pd

columns = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4","A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "prex"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
"""plt.ion()"""
plt.figure()
while not True:

    now = datetime.now()
    adata = 5 * np.random.randn(1,10) + 25.
    prex = 1e-10* np.random.randn(1,1) + 1e-10
    outcomes = np.append(adata, prex)
    ind = [now]
    idf = pd.DataFrame(np.array([outcomes]), index = ind, columns = columns)
    df = df.append(idf)
    ax = df.plot(secondary_y=['prex'])

    plt.show()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

But if I uncomment """plt.ion()""" I get many different windows open. Otherwise I have to close the window to get the updated plot.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I dunno but I just added a `matplotlib` tag to get some more views.  It seems like `bokeh` is more oriented towards real time stuff, so you might want to look into that.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the axes for [plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) to use instead of creating a different axes each time you call it. To redraw the plot in interactive mode you can use [draw](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.draw) instead of show.

```
from matplotlib import animation
import time as tm
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import pandas as pd

columns = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4","A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "prex"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create an axes. 
while True:

    now = datetime.now()
    adata = 5 * np.random.randn(1,10) + 25.
    prex = 1e-10* np.random.randn(1,1) + 1e-10
    outcomes = np.append(adata, prex)
    ind = [now]
    idf = pd.DataFrame(np.array([outcomes]), index = ind, columns = columns)
    df = df.append(idf)
    df.plot(secondary_y=['prex'], ax = ax) # Pass the axes to plot. 

    plt.draw() # Draw instead of show to update the plot in ion mode. 
    tm.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work, but It increases the number of lines at each refresh. I.E. at the first refresh I have 11 lines at the second 22 and so on and so forth.. Why is it so?

Comment: Try clearing the axes (ax.cla()) each iteration before plotting it.